# Reverse vector order in ARM NEON intrinsics

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

I'm trying to reverse the order of a 128 bit vector (uint16x8).

For example if I have

```
a b c d e f g h
```

I would like to obtain

```
h g f e d c b a
```

Is there a simple way to do that with NEON intrinsics?
I tried with the VREV but it doesn't work.

Comment: how did you try `vrev`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `vrev64.16` instruction however it doesn't swap between double registers of a single quad register. You need to achieve that using an additional `vswp`.

For intrinsics

```
q = vrev64q_u16(q)
```

should do the trick for swapping inside double words, then you need to swap double words in quad register. However that gets cumbersome since there is no `vswp` intrinsics directly which forces you to use something like

```
q = vcombine_u16(vget_high_u16(q), vget_low_u16(q))
```

which actually ends up as a `vswp` instruction.

See below for an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t s[] = {0x101, 0x102, 0x103, 0x104, 0x105, 0x106, 0x107, 0x108};
    uint16_t *t = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        t[i] = 0;
    }
    uint16x8_t a = vld1q_u16(s);
    a = vrev64q_u16(a);
    a = vcombine_u16(vget_high_u16(a), vget_low_u16(a));
    vst1q_u16(t, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("0x%3x ", t[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

which generates an assembly like below

```
vld1.16 {d16-d17}, [sp:64]
movs    r4, #0
vrev64.16   q8, q8
vswp    d16, d17
vst1.16 {d16-d17}, [r5]
```

and outputs

```
$ rev
0x108 0x107 0x106 0x105 0x104 0x103 0x102 0x101
```